# Unable to use the ORM .All() of Beego

Tags: orm, go

Here's an extremely simple piece of code that should work according to the documentation.

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    "fmt"
)

type TestController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

type Ticket struct {
    Id              int        `orm:"auto"`
    EventId         int
    EntryId         int
}

func (this *TestController) Get() {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    tickets := new([]*Ticket)

    qs, _ := o.QueryTable(new(Ticket)).Filter("EventId", 2).All(&tickets)

    fmt.Print(qs)

    this.Ctx.WriteString("test controller")
}


func init(){
    orm.RegisterModel(new(Ticket))
}
```

This results in Beego crashing with the following error:

```
GoEventKeeper:wrong object type `*[]*controllers.Ticket` for rows scan, need *[]*rohan.com/GoEventKeeper/controllers.Ticket or *rohan.com/GoEventKeeper/controllers.Ticket
```

I feel like this shouldn't be happening, obviously I only have one Ticket struct inside controllers so it seems to be comparing the wrong values with eachother?

What do i need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Guess: Your new returns a pointer already. Then you still take the address of it. Remove the ampersand or do `var tickets []*Tickets` isntead (as in the manual)

Comment: I tried that, it changes the error to: `wrong object type []*controllers.Ticket for rows scan, need *[]*rohan.com/GoEventKeeper/controllers.Ticket etc`

Answer (score 3):

```
qs, _ := o.QueryTable(new(Ticket)).Filter("EventId", 2).All(&tickets)
```

changes to

```
qs, _ := o.QueryTable(new(Ticket)).Filter("EventId", 2).All(tickets)
```

becasue tickets already is point

more detail please refer http://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/query.md#all